LSTM giving more generalize result with accuracy of 89% when using non sequential data while with sequential data 64%
I am working on time series classification. I have used two preprocessing steps given below

Time series Dataset --> Slicing Time Series ---> Train-Validation-Test-Split --> Model Training
Accuracy -- 90%

Time series Dataset --> Train-Validation-Test-Split --> Slicing Train/Test/Validation independently --> Model Training
Accuracy -- 64%


I am currently working on obtaining a sequential probability distribution for my project and have moved on to the second step. However, I am getting a lower accuracy result than expected, even lower than first step. I have already tuned hyperparameters and addressed the issue of class imbalance to eliminate bias, but the accuracy not increasing beyond 64%. Can anyone provide some insight into why this may be occurring?
For the train validation test split, I am using sklearn
x_main, x_test, y_main, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42,stratify=y,shuffle=True)
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_main, y_main, test_size= 0.1, random_state=42,stratify=y_main,shuffle=True)
At least I am expecting a close result of 80-85% with the second step

If I understood correctly, in the first method you define windows (short sequences) of data and then you shuffle the windows (not their contents, i.e. you preserve the sequential nature of the data). In the second method you simply shuffle all samples, which destroys the ordering information contained in the data.
Sequential models are designed to learn from patterns in the sequences where the order matters. When the data is randomly shuffled as in method 2, the ordering information is lost and the model doesn't perform as well. The first method preserves the ordering of samples within the windows, allowing the model to learn meaningful patterns and dependencies within each window, which I think is why it performs better.

At least I am expecting a close result of 80-85% with the second step

If your data is inherently sequential, I don't think method 2 is a suitable way of preprocessing the data as you lose the sequence information. If you proceed with method 2, then a recurrent model would not usually be a suitable choice. An MLP would be more appropriate, as MLPs treat each feature independently and they don't rely on sequential patterns. Though it still might not perform as well as method 1 + recurrent model.

In time series data, the instances of different classes are independent. After the data is sliced, the sequential information is considered.
In the first method, the sequential information is disrupted, but the accuracy is 90% with LSTM. In the second method, the sequential information is preserved, but the accuracy is only 64% for LSTM.
With MLP, I am getting 66%; this is happening because some of the time series of the different labels are overlapping perfectly.
But my question is why, with the first method, LSTM manages to give 90%, even with overlapping time series data points.

To me it seems like method 1 preserves the sequential nature of the data (because it uses windows), whereas method 2 doesn't (because it shuffles the individual samples). However, I think you are saying the opposite is true?

Method 2 performs the data split before slicing the time series data, whereas Method 1 splits the data after slicing.

Assuming only the windows are shuffled, and not their contents, I'd expect shuffling to perform better than no shuffling. This is mainly because you train the model one minibatch at a time. If the batches are shuffled, the model sees a diverse set of examples at each step (a better representation of the data's overall distribution), which helps convergence.

I think this is by luck that we are getting accuracy of 90% due to randomization. If I change the random state and split percentage the accuracy reduces to 60-66% which is desirable as there are some data point which perfectly overlapping  and impossible to classify.
